# Clr Dll loaded by test prog but not by calling app

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, loading

I want to develop a plugin for a program (EXE) to interop with an external C# module. The plugin is one of the three dlls needed: this dll (A) calls a wrapper dll (Native/Managed, in C++/Cli) (B) to interop with a C# dll (C).

A is supposed to be loaded by a calling program (EXE) when deployed.

In testing, a message from the C# dll is displayed, which tells me dll A is correctly loaded by a C++ tester and subsequently has made successful call to other dlls.

In deployment, dll A is loaded by EXE if it only displays a message. However, when lines of code to call dll B are added, EXE no longer recognizes dll A.

I have made sure that all files are in the right place. So I think the problem lies in the extra lines of interop code to call dll B. Any idea as to where I should look for problem?

Here is the exported function in dll A:

```
int WINAPI Init()
{
    FILE * pConsole;
    AllocConsole();
    freopen_s(&pConsole, "CONOUT$", "wb", stdout);
    printf("Started\n");

    //These two line below call the wrapper dll B
    // which serves as a middle man between dlls A and C
    NativeExport_ClientWrapper* client = createMyClass();
    if (client) client->Test();

    return 1;
}
```

Here is the unmanaged side of the wrapper B:

```
//----------------------------------------------
//NativeExport_ClientWrapper.h
//----------------------------------------------
//#pragma once

#pragma once
#pragma unmanaged

#define THISDLL_EXPORTS
#ifdef THISDLL_EXPORTS
#define THISDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define THISDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


class ILBridge_ClientWrapper;
class NativeExport_ClientWrapper {
private:
    ILBridge_ClientWrapper* __bridge;
public:
    NativeExport_ClientWrapper();
public:
    ~NativeExport_ClientWrapper();
public:
    THISDLL_API void Test();

};
extern "C" THISDLL_API  NativeExport_ClientWrapper* createMyClass();
```

And here is the managed side of the wrapper:

```
//----------------------------------------------
//ILBridge_ClientWrapper.h
//----------------------------------------------
#pragma once
#pragma managed
#include <vcclr.h>

class ILBridge_ClientWrapper {
private:
    gcroot<Client^> __Impl;
public:
    ILBridge_ClientWrapper() {
        __Impl = gcnew Client;
    }
    void Test() {
        __Impl->test();

    }

};
```

Comment: It is a very brittle way to activate managed code, any exception it throws becomes completely undiagnosable.  You need to debug it, change the debugger type from auto to mixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exhaustive search, I found nothing that helps to resolve this issue, including doing library load debugging.

My other related posting is here: [Unexpected Stackoverflow exception using CLR in a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646573/unexpected-stackoverflow-exception-using-clr-in-a-dll?noredirect=1#comment45591301_28646573)

And finally, by doing several things, this exception is gone and everything works now:

1) In my CS project, I use the unmanagedexports package (use NuGet package manager to install it: Install-Package unmanagedexports) to export static methods using the __stdcall calling convention. In this project, you need to add these:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
```

2) add the path to the wrapper header files to the unmanaged C/C++ project's property page (C/C++->general->additional include directories)

3) put the managed and native wrapper into one project/dll (built with /clr option), separate them from the other two modules (one for the managed C# and one for the unmanaged C/C++)

4) optionally, I added a definition file for the unmanaged C/C++ functions

5) make sure all modules are built against the same framework and platform. In my case, I use framework 4.0 and x86 platform. In some case, you need to add an app.config file with the following:

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>"
```

6) set the path in the environment pointing to where the dlls are deployed

That's about it.